# How to check if another node exists in an xml without reading - C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I would like to implement code that deserializes an xml into a list of objects. I found a problem in the code where the while reads forward so every other node is skipped. What is the proper way to check for a next node in an xml to be implemented in the while loop of this code?

```
private Task<List<TAxEntity>> Deserialize(XmlReader reader)
    {
        var deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TAxEntity));
        var entities = new List<TAxEntity>();

        do
        {
            using (var stringReader = new StringReader(reader.ReadOuterXml()))
            {
                var entity = (TAxEntity)deserializer.Deserialize(stringReader);

                entities.Add(entity);
            }
        }
        while (reader.ReadToNextSibling(EntityElementName));

        return Task.FromResult(entities);
    }
```

Comment: The skipping is caused by ReadToNextSibling.  Find some other way to know when you're at the end, because ReadOuterXml is already advancing your stream.

Comment: Yes, I realized that, which is why I am looking for another solution to look forward without doing that read. Thanks!

Comment: `while (reader.Read()) { ... }` ?

Comment: @PiLHA, I am looking for something to check but not read ahead

Comment: [`XmlReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) *Represents a reader that provides fast, noncached, forward-only access to XML data.*  So there isn't really a way to look ahead (or, equivalently, seek backwards after reading ahead).  You'll need to restructure your code so that looking forward or backward isn't necessary -- or load the entire XML into an `XDocument` for easy querying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check that an `XmlReader` is already correctly positioned, you can check whether [`reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.nodetype.aspx) and [`reader.Name == EntityElementName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.name.aspx).  Then, if the reader is already correctly positioned, do not scan forward using `ReadToNextSibling()`.

However, there are a few improvements to be made to your algorithm:

1. Instead of checking for the correct `reader.Name`, check whether the [`LocalName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.localname.aspx) and [`NamespaceURI`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.namespaceuri.aspx) are as expected, and if not, call [`reader.ReadToNextSibling(string localName,string namespaceURI)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w0sea4t.aspx).  This avoids hardcoding of namespace prefixes, which is a [bug to be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8597473/3744182).
2. Rather than `ReadOuterXml()`, call [`reader.ReadSubtree()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree.aspx) and pass the returned reader directly to `deserializer.Deserialize()`.  Your current algorithm parses the XML, reformats it into a second XML string, then parses that string a second time.  Using `ReadSubtree()` allows the `XmlSerializer` to stream a nested element directly from the incoming `XmlReader` and so avoids this extra parsing and reformatting.

Putting all this together, you can introduce the following lower-level extension method:

```
public static class XmlReaderExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TElement> DeserializeSequence<TElement>(this XmlReader reader, string localEntityElementName, string namespaceURI)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TElement));
        while ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == localEntityElementName && reader.NamespaceURI == namespaceURI)
            || reader.ReadToNextSibling(localEntityElementName, namespaceURI))
        {
            // Using ReadSubtree instead of ReadOuterXml() avoids having do parse, reformat, then parse the formatted XML a second time
            // by reading directly from the current stream only once.
            TElement element;
            using (var subReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
            {
                element = (TElement)deserializer.Deserialize(subReader);
            }
            // Consume the EndElement also (or move past the current element if reader.IsEmptyElement).
            reader.Read();
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

And modify your `Deserialize()` method to be as follows:

```
    private Task<List<TAxEntity>> Deserialize(XmlReader reader)
    {
        var entities = reader.DeserializeSequence<TAxEntity>(EntityElementName, "" /* Pass the correct namespace here */).ToList();

        return Task.FromResult(entities);
    }
```

Sample [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XnVjRL).

Note that any manual `XmlReader` code should be unit-tested with both indented and unindented XML, since bugs that involve skipping nodes are sometimes masked when parsing indented XML (because the whitespace nodes get skipped.)